# click functionality not working in child divs in react inside return

Tags: javascript, reactjs, agora.io

I have this react code where onClick doesn't seem to be working on the child divs. However it works fine on the parent div.
Here is the exact code that I am referring to .

```
https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/OpenAgoraWeb-React/blob/master/src/components/AgoraVideoCall/index.jsx
```

It puzzled me as how this is happening ?Why is child div inside return not working onClick ?
What can the reason behind this ?
 onClick on div "ag-canvas" is working  but not on any div inside that .

```jsx
componentDidMount() {
    // add listener to control btn group
    let canvas = document.querySelector('#ag-canvas')
    canvas.classList.add('active');
    let btnGroup = document.querySelector('.ag-btn-group')
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', () => {
        if (global._toolbarToggle) {
            clearTimeout(global._toolbarToggle)
        }
        btnGroup.classList.add('active')
        global._toolbarToggle = setTimeout(function () {
            btnGroup.classList.remove('active')
        }, 2000)
    })
}

render() {
    const exitBtn = (
        <span
          onClick={this.handleExit}
          className={this.state.readyState ? 'ag-btn exitBtn' : 'ag-btn exitBtn disabled'}
          title="Exit">
          <i className="ag-icon ag-icon-leave"></i>
        </span>
    )

    return (
        <div id="ag-canvas"   style={style}>
            <div className="navbarVideoCalling">
                <div onClick={this.backIcon} className="back_icon">
                    <img src={back_icon} />
                </div>
                <div onClick={()=>console.log("working")} className="liveheader">
                    <span>Live</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="ag-btn-group">
                {exitBtn}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Post your function which you trying to execute. also post where it is working and where it is failing with what error.

Comment: When you select the `div`, you are using a query selector to select a `class` (which is generally returned as a list) not a single `div`. Have you tried giving the `div` an `id` and using that to add the onClickListener?